# redirection log using rsyslog

Tags: linux, redirect, logging, rsyslog

I add this line on rsyslog.conf:

```
if $msg contains 'arpwatch'          then          /var/log/test.log
```

The problem is if I a have simultaneous lines of logs containing the expression (arpwatch), then tonly the first line is logged and the others aren't.

How I can modify my expression to write to the log if i have simultaneous lines containing "arpwatch"?

If these lines are sent to rsyslog:

```
2012 Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault->/var/log/syslog Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault arpwatch_eth0: chdir(/usr/arpwatch): No such file or directory
2012 Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault->/var/log/syslog Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault arpwatch_eth0: (using current working directory)
2012 Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault->/var/log/syslog Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault arpwatch_eth0: pcap open eth0: eth0: No such device exists (SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)
```

then on `/var/log/test.log` i have  this line:

```
2012 Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault->/var/log/syslog Nov 10 09:56:34 alienvault arpwatch_eth0: chdir(/usr/arpwatch): No such file or director
```

and the others are ignored

Answer (score 0):

You check the msg property of rsyslog for the pattern `arpwatch` - but it's really only in the logged message... the `arpwatch_eth0` is not part of msg

Answer (score 0):

```
$template usermsg,"%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %programname% %syslogfacility-text%.%syslogseverity-text% :%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg::drop-last-lf%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate usermsg

if $programname == 'arpwatch' and $msg contains 'arpwatch' then /var/log/test.log
```